# Why this python code doesn't work?

Tags: python, loops

Can you help me with this code?

```
s = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

def group(s):
    lst = []
    temp_lst = []
    for i in s:
        if len(temp_lst) == 0:
            temp_lst.append(i)
            continue
        if temp_lst[0] == i:
            temp_lst.append(i)
        else:
            lst.append(temp_lst)
            del temp_lst[:]
            temp_lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

It returns:

```
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Why?

My desired output is:

```
[[1, 1], [3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: You are filling the outer list with references to the same inner list; `del tmp_lst[:]` empties the existing list, you never create a new one. Also note that `itertools.groupby` would help you out.

Comment: Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): `[list(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]`

Answer (score 2):

This works: Replaced `del temp_lst[:]` by `temp_lst = []`

```
s = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

def group(s):
    lst = []
    temp_lst = []
    for i in s:
        if len(temp_lst) == 0:
            temp_lst.append(i)
            continue
        if temp_lst[0] == i:
            temp_lst.append(i)
        else:
            lst.append(temp_lst)
            temp_lst = []
            temp_lst.append(i)
    lst.append(temp_lst)
    return lst

print group(s)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

What `del temp_lst[:]` does is that it deletes all entries of the list. The key to understand here is that you operate by reference and you need to point `temp_list` to a new list so you don't operate on the old list you just put into `lst`

Doing `temp_list = []` leaves the old list (which you just inserted into `lst`) and assigns the variable (you can think of a pointer) to a new empty list which is not associated with the just inserted list.

As jonrsharpe correctly notes above a better solution would be `itertools.groupby`:

```
s = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
[list(l[1]) for l in itertools.groupby(s)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now!

Comment: @a_z_s you welcome, I added the `groupby` solution, which is what python offers out of the box, it's most probably better to use this solution instead

Comment: @a_z_s oh and you forgot to add the last `temp_lst` into `lst`, I corrected that in the code above as well